# Entity Framework DbSet contains 0 records

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework-5

So I have the following problem:

I have some Vehicle entity that corresponds to a table in the DB. But when I try to retrieve ALL the records with the following line :

```
var vehicles = db.VehicleSet.ToList();
```

I get ZERO objects as result ... whilst the table in the DB has approx. 18k records.

Any idea where the problem might be, or is the question too vague?

Comment: What happens if you do `db.VehicleSet.Take(10).ToList()`?

Comment: It's a bit vague. But since it compiles and runs, I'd start by checking you're connecting to the correct database.

Comment: @dav_i, same result - vehicles count(0);

Comment: @KristofClaes, I already checked, I am connecting to the right one.

Comment: Could you post the code of the VehicleSet entity, the mapping and your DbContext?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Figured it out. Turns out it was a problem with the Database. In my structure I was using a "Discriminator" field which was not set and was causing problems.

Thank you for your time.