# C# entity framework console. Why my returned data count is 0

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hello i have one problem. I cant get any data from my simple console app with Entity Framework. Database in on localdb and table is filled. all names are correct. if i change model class i get error so it means my entity framework connect with this db. Can u explain me why i cant get any datas? 
       `Console.WriteLine(baseD.ConsoleEntities.Count());` returns 0 when there should be 3 rows.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var baseD = new ConsoleDbContext();
        Console.WriteLine(baseD.ConsoleEntities.Count());
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}



public class ConsoleDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> ConsoleEntities { get; set; } 
}
public class Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21258462/entity-framework-dbset-contains-0-records help?

Comment: You would need to provide more information or a meaningful answer.  What version of Entity Framework are you using?

Comment: Newest Entity framework and not, didnt helped.

Comment: Your connection string, please

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConsoleDbContext" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=ConsoleTest;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: You should use `using` to create the context, in this way the `dispose` is automatically called.

Comment: still nothing :/

Comment: Are you sure, you have some items in your database? Are you sure you are connected to the right database? Does `ConsoleEntities.Add()` and `baseD.Save()` before getting the count does make any difference?

Comment: Its creaing new table named Entities :o

Comment: Why name of new table is Enities if i didnt declare it?!

Comment: What's the table name? If it's `Consoles` rename the class to `Console` instead of `Entity`. If the table name is singular (like `Console`) read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7924758/entity-framework-creates-a-plural-table-name-but-the-view-expects-a-singular-ta

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the ConnString to the DbContext, try this:

```
public class ConsoleDbContext : DbContext
{
  public ConsoleDbContext ()
    : base("name=ConsoleDbContext")
  { }

  public DbSet<Entity> ConsoleEntities { get; set; } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I GET IT!
So.. my model class named "Entity" is changed to "Entities" and ENTITIES is name of table. Why? because Entity framework adds 's' or 'es' to end of name cuz of "PluralizingTableNameConvention". Changes what repaired that test-learn project is changing name of table to Entities from entity or disable PluralizingTableNameConvention in Entity framework. Thanks for all answers!